# Weak convergence of sequence of polynomials.

Tags: functional-analysis

A sequence $(x_n)$ in a normed linear space $X$ is said to converge weakly to $x$ if
$$ \lim _{n\rightarrow\infty} \ell(x_n) = \ell(x)$$
Consider the sequence $(f_n) \in C([0,1])$ defined by $$f_n(t) = t^n.$$
Does this sequence converge weakly? Does it have weakly convergent subsequences?

I don't really see the sequences here, do we get one different sequence depending on what $t$ is? $ \lim _{n\rightarrow\infty} \ell f_n(t) = 0, $ for $t \neq 1$. So it seems that f would converge to something not continuous?

Comment: You did not correctly state what weak convergence means.  What is $\ell$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider evaluation functionals
$$
\mathrm{ev}_t:C([0,1])\to\mathbb{C}:f\mapsto f(t)
$$
Assume $(f_n)$ weakly converges to $f\in C([0,1])$, then 
$$
f(t)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{ev}_t(f_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(t)=
\begin{cases}
0\quad\mbox{ if }\quad t\neq 1\\
1\quad\mbox{ if }\quad t= 1
\end{cases}
$$ 
Thus $f$ is discontinuous at $1$. Contradiction, so there is no weak limit for $(f_n)$. The same argument shows that $(f_n)$ have no weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, for any $x \in [0,1]$ don't you have a functional $\ell_x$ given by $\ell_x(f)=f(x)$. Which would mean that weak convergence implies point-wise convergence. The sequence converges pointwise to $\chi_{\{1\}}$, so I don't see how it could have a weak limit.

Comment: @JacobSchlather, thanks your idea is much simpler

Comment: @DamianSobota thank you!